# Volley response handling in multiple request

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-volley, android-tabs

I have view pager with two tabs both request data from server and gets at the same time using volley.

I have written an interface to notify when data is received and display on each fragment.

But the problem is that the response I am getting sometimes are same even if I pass different request tag for both request.

I get the same data for both request hence causing exception in other fragment.

And this is random sometime both returned different data, sometime first request data is received on both fragment and sometime for second fragment.

Here is sample code:

```
public interface OnResponse{ 
     public void jsonResponse(JSONObject response);
     public void jsonResponse(JSONObject response, String tag);//also tried this but same result response are returned
}
```

then in volley `Response.Listener<JSONObject>() onResponse(JSONObject response)` I call `responseListener.jsonResponse(response);` 
OR `responseListener.jsonResponse(response,tag)` .

What can I do to separate both response as Context/Activity is same due to fragment pager(as I initialize My request manager class with current context and its has two view pager fragment tabs).

Or Is there a way to call request method when I select the second tab first time?

Or Is there a way to call send request method from first fragment and receive response in other fragment?

Can I use volley priority in this case OR RequestFuture?

(Don't want to use Handler postDelayed.)

Please help.

Comment: I would suggest including your code.  Without seeing the code it will be difficult for people to suggest reasons for the behavior you are seeing or resolutions.